# Inserting values into Solr boolean fields

Tags: indexing, lucene, solr

I'm trying to insert a value into a boolean field in solr by passing it as a field in a doc, thus:

```
<add>
<doc>
<field name="WouldBuySameModelAgain">value-here</field>
</doc>
</add>
```

The field definition in schema.xml is:

```
<field name="WouldBuySameModelAgain" type="boolean" index="false" stored="true" required="false" />
```

I haven't been able to find any documentation on what value should be used where it says "value-here" in my example. I have tried true & false, True & False, TRUE & FALSE, 1 & 0 all to no avail - there are still no documents in my index with a value in the boolean field. All of my non-boolean fields with stored="true" are getting values.

All suggestions welcomed.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The answer is "true" or "false", doesn't appear to be case sensitive. For example:

```
<field name="WouldBuySameModelAgain">true</field>
```

An error elsewhere in my app was putting an empty string in where I was expecting a value.

Comment: Currently the reference guide says that "Values of "1", "t", or "T" in the first character are interpreted as true. Any other values in the first character are interpreted as false."